# converting normal java code to hadoop code without mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, compression, hdfs

i am currently working on hadoop. i want to convert my java code to hadoop. i want my code to work with hdfs. i.e. my code  is normal file system, i want it to work with hdfs(hd file system). i want the below code to work in hadoop(hd file system).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class GZIPExample {

    public static void gzip() {
        int i = new File("/media/0052ADF152ADEC1A/all splits").list().length;
        System.out.println(i + "here");
        while (i > 0) {
            String file = "/media/0052ADF152ADEC1A/all splits/File" + i + ".txt";
            String gzipFile = "/media/0052ADF152ADEC1A/compress/Filegz" + i + ".gz";
            String newFile = "/media/0052ADF152ADEC1A/all/hadoop ebooks/test1.txt";

            compressGzipFile(file, gzipFile);

            decompressGzipFile(gzipFile, newFile);
            i--;
        }
    }

    private static void decompressGzipFile(String gzipFile, String newFile) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(gzipFile);
            GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            //close resources
            fos.close();
            gis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void compressGzipFile(String file, String gzipFile) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(gzipFile);
            GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                gzipOS.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            //close resources
            gzipOS.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to start reading and understanding what a MapReduce code looks like and what it has to achieve:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html

Then you will understand that there is not "conversion". In a very high level view, MapReduce Java code is a way to structure your code in two phases: Map and Reduce

By your example, it looks like you want to un/compress a high amount of files using parallel computing so you should try to write your MapReduce code as a two step process of un/compressing a file. Sorry but I have never faced compression algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

An example of Java code and dealing with Hadoop File system example is given here :

https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-directory-in-hdfs-using-hadoop-filesystem-api

You can keep this as a reference.